# magento inability to log in with admin account

Tags: magento

My problem is that, i cant log into the Admin area of Magento with admin account.
When i create dummy accounts, they log in just fine though.

Ive tried multiple "resolutions" but none work for me or arent applicable to my situation.
I also tried one on here where you had to comment out certain lines but again, no good.

This is a new installation (2nd time) on my WAMP server and i access it via 127.0.0.1

The problem i get is that when i log in, i get a "invalid login or password" **even though** i know its correct.

i looked at the admin_users table and my account is in there (user/pass) but the pass is under some encryption...im goign to assume md5. I tried to change it manually and nothing.

i also tried the default "admin" username and "123123" pass but...the only way to log in is with an email so that didnt work.

Nothing i do works

the version im using is ver. 1.6.2.0

Any ideas /tips/changes/links etc ill gladly accept.

Thank you in advanced.

Mike

Comment: What 'other' ways did you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reset the password manually through phpMyAdmin then be sure you set the field type to MD5.

Try running this query in phpMyAdmin under the SQL tab:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
```

Then go to your store's admin and login with `admin` and `qXpassword`

(from [MagentoCommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password))

Comment: Hi there, i had tried a similar query and nothing, i took this one you provided, put it in, and all green but nothing...let me ask you this, is the login area for an admin different than where a normal user logs in?

Comment: because no matter what it doesnt register.

Comment: Yall can close this...not sure what happened...i reinstalled and on the 3rd and final try it works......

Comment: `is the login area for an admin different than where a normal user logs in?` Of course it is different, in your case it should be `127.0.0.1/admin`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a fake domain insted of 127? modify your hosts file to add something like:

```
127.0.0.1 magento.dev
```